# Failing to create a .exe file with Python and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, py2exe

I`m trying to make an executable from my python script called *ProyectoNew.py*. It works with a folder called *"Imagenes"* and another called *"ModulosExternos"*, and a PyQT5's .ui file like this:

[image]

Here`s the Code posted in GitHub: https://github.com/TheFlosh/ProyectoSoftware.git

I`ve tried to use *Pyinstaller*, *Py2Exe* and *CXFreeze* but it didn't worked. Using each one of these modules to create a .exe file I've got the same result when I tried to execute it in another PC, as shown here:

[image: LEFT: What I get after using pyinstaller - Right: What I need to show]

On the LEFT of the picture you can see what I get after using  pyinstaller (or Py2Exe), on the right you can see what I need to show.

Here are the modules that I use in my code ("ModulosExternos" is the folder where I put some particular modules that my code needs):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import pyttsx3
from pyttsx3.drivers import sapi5   
import PyQt5                        
import sip                          
import os                          
from ModulosExternos import Boton_1,Boton_2,Boton_3,Boton_4,Boton_Final,Listas_Pictogramas, Frases_Completas
```

And here is the last part of it, to instantiate the GUI:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = ProyectoNew()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I`ve read a lot of posts on the internet that recommended creating  *Setup.Py* file to initiate the process of creating an executable file of my project. These are some examples of what I did with two of them:

With CX_Freeze:

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

files = ['icono.ico','/Imagenes']

target = Executable(
    script = "/ProyectoNew.py",
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    )

#Setup 
setup(
    name = "Proyect2",
    version = "1.6",
    description = "Software",
    author = "----",
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files' : files}},
    executables = [target]
    )
```

With Py2Exe:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = "Proyect2",
    version="1.0",
    description = "Software",
    executables = [Executable("ProyectoNew.py")],)
```

With *Pyinstaller* I typed: *python --nowindowed --onefile ProyectoNew.py* but I constantly got the same result as shown before.

I think that when I execute *Pyinstaller*, the .exe file doesn`t load the modules and the images that I use. What am I missing while creating the file? What do I need to do to execute the .exe file in another PC?.

I would prefer to use *pyinstaller*,but using any one of these will help me.

Answer (score 3):

What's is wrong with that? You get some kind of error? Please edit your question with that.

With pyinstaller and this command, you should be able easily build an executable file:

```
pyinstaller [FILE].py -w -F
```

This command generate a /dist folder with the neccesary files and .exe file to run

*-w param is for do not provide a console window for standard i/o

*-F param is for one-file bundled executable
You can check more params [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options)

PD: Before, you need obviously install pyinstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your answer. Yes, I've tried exactly as you wrote it, but I get the same "error" as shown in the images of my post.

Comment: @PabloFlores Ok, I understand and I think that I know what happens. You need add the images and other assets that you need to the build. Read [this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle)

Comment: Hi again. I read this before asking my question, and I did what it says there. I've also watched several videos and threads about "adding data" in the spec file, but I still get the "black" images. I`ve also try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&t=319s